# VBA - Sort column by the closest value to answer. Closest answer will appear at the top of the sorted list

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I am trying to automatically sort a column in excel using VBA.

I want the closest value to my answer (my answer is found in sheet 2 but its hidden) to appear at the top of the sorted list. (The answer will be in a separate sheet, say sheet2, but my list will be in sheet1)

for example, my answer is 4,000 and the closest answer is 3,998. I want the row where the answer is 3,998 to be shifted to the top of the list and likewise sort for all the other rows. So the whole list will be sorted based on which ones are the closest to the answer.

This is the sorting code I found online, but idk how to include the part where I can sort according to my answer in another cell. Is that even possible?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error Resume Next
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
Range("B1").Sort Key1:=Range("B2"), _
Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a helper column.
Use the formula `=ABS(B2-Sheet2!$A$1)` (assuming your answer is in A1 of sheet2).
Sort by the helper column.

Record a macro that does the sort, so you can see the code Excel creates. It's more wordy than the code you tend to find online, so you may have to trim it down, but the code should work.

Comment: I tried recording a macro on sorting out the values. But I selected Sort from "Smallest to Largest" by using Filter found in Excel ribbon. The recorded code is actually very similar to the one i found online.., I would paste it here but there is a limit to the no. of characters in the comments. Where can I include `=ABS(B2-Sheet2!$A$1)` in the recorded macro? I am really not sure..so sorry about it..

Comment: ok...so i digged deeper and did you mean something like this:
` =INDEX(A1:A20,MATCH(MIN(ABS(A1:A20-D1)),ABS(A1:A20-D1),0))` ? But am I also able to do this in VBA? Whereby `If col <> "" Then` ....Then sort using the formula?

Comment: Add an extra column to the data you are trying to sort that has the formula I suggested. Sort on that column. The reason I suggested to record the macro was so you could see how it was done. You can run that macro each time